# Using std::variant in g++

Tags: c++, stl, g++, variant

How can I use `std::variant` in `g++`? Why isn't there `std::variant` in `std::experimental` (though `std::optional` is)? What version of `g++` do I need? I prefer not to use `boost` and I'd like to use standard library only.

Edit: it seems like only `g++ 7` supports `std::variant`. Then my question is: when will it be released and what problems may I encounter when using its experimental version?

Comment: You should use the very latest version of `g++`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what is the version number? How can I get it?

Comment: Run `g++ -v` or `g++ --version` in a terminal

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know my version number. I have `g++-6.2` and `g++-5.4`. They  do not have `variant` unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z) says, that GCC 7 has `std::variant`.

Comment: Yep, I see. How can I install it on Ubuntu? Or as I found out, GCC 7 has not been released yet, when will it be?

Comment: @AleksandrTukallo: Simply with download, configure; make; make install. Works perfect!

Comment: @Klaus thanks! But what problems may I encounter when using it before release? Is it ok?

Comment: @AleksandrTukallo: It is in stage 3 which means that there are a number of open bugs which should be fixed in the next days. Maybe you run into one of them. But I believe that you even run faster in a unfixed bug of an older gcc version as in a new one from current pre release branch. Short answer: Give it a chance! You can have as many versions in parallel as you want. If it do not work: Write a bug report. It will help others!

Answer (score 2):

GCC has an [info page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z) where you can check which language feature was implemented with which version. It looks like `variant` is not yet implemented.

Comment: According to the table `std::optional` is also not implemented, though I can use it in my `g++ 5.4`: [experimental optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/optional).

Comment: There is always [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: @user2393256 Does the link list standard library status or only core language features?